# How to add a random element from an array to another blank array?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a simple restaurant menu by javascript . First the menu will display 5 dishes (which stores in array "menu"). Then when I click the button "Order" , a random dish from the array "menu" will be display in the line "Orders" one by one as I keep clicking it. To do this I generated random number from 0-4 and created 2nd blank array "Orders" and create DOM objects to write "Orders" array's element one by one in the HTML line. Code is below

```js
const menu = ["Steak", "Potato", "Hamburger", "Salad", "Cheesecake"];
let show_menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
let show_orders = document.querySelector("#orders");
for (let i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++) {
  if (menu[i] != undefined) {
    show_menu.textContent += ` 　　　　 ${menu[i]}`;
  }
}

function chuumon() {
  let orders = [];
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.querySelector("#num").textContent = a;
  orders.push(menu[a]);
  show_orders.textContent = orders[a];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>restaurant order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <span id="menu"></span>
  <hr> Orders:
  <span id="orders"></span><br>
  <span id="num"></span>
  <button onclick="chuumon()">Order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is when I hit the button "Order" in the line "Orders" it only shows the `element[0]` of array `menu` otherwise it didn't show anything.

What's wrong with my `push()` method? (`orders.push(menu[a])`)

Now I want to set up an event when click the button "Serve" the dish at first in Line "Orders" will be deleted one by one. So I set up another function "Teikyo()" to use **function_name.shift()** methoad but struggling with access the "Order" Array values inside function "chuumon()" .Here is my code about these 2 functions. Can anyone suggest for me how to access into other function's property?

```
function chuumon() {
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
show_orders.textContent = menu.join(",");
orders.push(menu[a]);
show_orders.textContent = orders;
last_order.textContent = orders[orders.length - 1]
   }
function teikyo()
  {
chuumon().orders.shift();
show_orders.textContent = orders;
  }
```

Comment: `i <= menu.length` should be `i < menu.length`. Then you wouldn't need to check for `undefined`.

Comment: Barmar thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an index into `menu`. It won't be the correct index into `orders`, since this array will usually be shorter than `menu`. You should show `menu[a]` in `show_orders`, not `orders[a]`.

`orders` should be declared and initialized outside the function. Otherwise you keep resetting it to an empty array, instead of collecting all the ordered items.

```js
const menu = ["Steak", "Potato", "Hamburger", "Salad", "Cheesecake"];
let orders = [];

let show_menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
let show_orders = document.querySelector("#orders");
for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  show_menu.textContent += ` 　　　　 ${menu[i]}`;
}

function chuumon() {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * menu.length);
  document.querySelector("#num").textContent = a;
  orders.push(menu[a]);
  show_orders.textContent = menu[a];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>restaurant order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <span id="menu"></span>
  <hr> Orders:
  <span id="orders"></span><br>
  <span id="num"></span>
  <button onclick="chuumon()">Order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you mean I should delete the array "Order" and parse the menu[a] directly into the DOM object show_orders?

Comment: No, you should declare it outside the function so it will hold all the items that were ordered.

Comment: I'm very grateful of your thoughtful suggest. I will fix it and see what the result will come later

Comment: It works when I declare the Order array outside my main function!

Answer (score 0):

That is nothing wrong with `orders.push(menu[a])` it is pushing the array properlly, however, you actually don't need the `orders.push(menu[a])` as you are initiating it everytime you call the function.

You can simply do:

```
function chuumon() {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.querySelector("#num").textContent = a;
  show_orders.textContent = menu[a];
}
```

```js
const menu = ["Steak", "Potato", "Hamburger", "Salad", "Cheesecake"];

let show_menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
let show_orders = document.querySelector("#orders");
for (let i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++) {
  if (menu[i] != undefined) {
    show_menu.textContent += ` 　　　　 ${menu[i]}`;
  }
}

function chuumon() {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.querySelector("#num").textContent = a;
  show_orders.textContent = menu[a];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>restaurant order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <span id="menu"></span>
  <hr> Orders:
  <span id="orders"></span><br>
  <span id="num"></span>
  <button onclick="chuumon()">Order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, if you want to push something on that array and keep track, you need to declare it outside your function.

```js
const menu = ["Steak", "Potato", "Hamburger", "Salad", "Cheesecake"];
let orders = [];
let show_menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
let show_orders = document.querySelector("#orders");
let show_order = document.querySelector("#order");
for (let i = 0; i <= menu.length; i++) {
  if (menu[i] != undefined) {
    show_menu.textContent += ` 　　　　 ${menu[i]}`;
  }
}

function chuumon() {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  document.querySelector("#num").textContent = a;
  show_orders.textContent = menu[a];
  orders.push(menu[a]);
  show_orders.textContent = orders;
  show_order.textContent = orders[orders.length - 1]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>restaurant order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <span id="menu"></span>
  <hr> Orders:
  <span id="orders"></span><br>
  <span id="num"></span>
  <hr> Last Order:
  <span id="order"></span><br>
  <button onclick="chuumon()">Order</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @caivisk thank for your sugest I will try then tell the result

Comment: When I declare it outside the function it work! I'm figuring out why:))

Comment: Because when declared outside it is not getting overriden... The way you coded, the variable was getting overrided everytime you call the function...

Answer (score 0):

***Problem:*** If it hasn't already been mentioned, your empty array `orders` is defined within the function. When a function is finished, all values within said function are garbage collected (deleted from memory -- gone). Every click of the button runs a the function with an empty `orders` array every time. The only text that'll show up is "steak" because you happen to get 0 of course, but what happens when the index is 3 (or anything other than 0)?:

```
orders = [];
menu[0] = 'steak';
orders.push('steak');
orders[0] = 'steak';
// Next click
orders = [];
menu[3] = 'salad';
orsers.push('salad');
orders[3] = ??????
// The length of orders is always 1
```

***Solution:*** Do not create a new array, it's pointless. The nature of the function is that of an event handler. It works with the array once every click and nothing else.

```js
const items = ["Steak", "Potato", "Hamburger", "Salad", "Cheesecake"];
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

items.forEach(item => menu.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<li>${item}</li>`));

function orderItem(e) {
  let order = document.querySelector('.order');
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  order.textContent = ` ${index+1}.  ${items[index]}`;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', orderItem);
```

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: -10px 0 -6px 0;
}

b {
  font: 2ch/1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>restaurant order</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu</h4>
  <ol class="menu"></ol>
  <hr>
  <button>Order</button><b> :</b>&nbsp;
  <output class='order'></output>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my edit path about adding another event with button "Serve" to delete one by one the dish showed in "Orders" linne. Here is my relate code and I tested it successfully.If you want to access a DOM object property just add the **.value** after the name of object.

```
function chuumon() {
 let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
 show_orders.textContent = menu.join(",");
 orders.push(menu[a]);
 show_orders.textContent = orders;
 last_order.textContent = orders[orders.length - 1];
    }

function teikyo(){
  orders.shift(show_orders.value);
  show_orders.textContent = orders;
  first_serve.textContent = orders.shift(show_orders.value);
  }
```